# Read file content per row of Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

We have an AWS S3 bucket with millions of documents in a complex hierarchy, and a CSV file with (among other data) links to a subset of those files, I estimate this file will be about 1000 to 10.000 rows. I need to join the data from the CSV file with the contents of the documents for further processing in Spark. In case it matters, we're using Scala and Spark 2.4.4 on an Amazon EMR 6.0.0 cluster.

I can think of two ways to do this. First is to add a transformation on the CSV `DataFrame` that adds the content as a new column:

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").load("<csv file>")
val attempt1 = df.withColumn("raw_content", spark.sparkContext.textFile($"document_url"))
```

or variations thereof (for example, wrapping it in a `udf`) don't seem to work, I think because `sparkContext.textFile` returns an RDD, so I'm not sure it's even supposed to work this way? Even if I get it working, is the best way to keep it performant in Spark?

An alternative I tried to think of is to use `spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles` upfront and then join the two dataframes together:

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").load("<csv file>")
val contents = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("<s3 bucket>").toDF("document_url", "raw_content");
val attempt2 = df.join(contents, df("document_url") === contents("document_url"), "left")
```

but `wholeTextFiles` doesn't go into subdirectories and the needed paths are hard to predict, and I'm also unsure of the performance impact of trying to build an RDD of the entire bucket of millions of files if I only need a small fraction of it, since the S3 API probably doesn't make it very fast to list all the objects in the bucket.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did figure out a solution in the end:

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").load("<csv file>")
val allS3Links = df.map(row => row.getAs[String]("document_url")).collect()
val joined = allS3Links.mkString(",")
val contentsDF = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(joined).toDF("document_url", "raw_content");
```

The downside to this solution is that it pulls all the urls to the driver, but it's workable in my case (100,000 * ~100 char length strings is not that much) and maybe even unavoidable.